# Manage External User button from Lightning Experience

Tags: community, lightning-experience, user-management, developer-edition, winter18

With Winter 18, Salesforce has provided the ability to Manage External users from Lightning Experience.But, I don't see the Manage External User button on Lightning Experience.

I did go through below link but still don't shows up.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213565&type=1

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm

[image]

Comment: you have communities enabled in your org?

Comment: communities are enabled.Currently, I am trying to switch it to Classic view to login as Community User.This is in Developer Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Communities related buttons would appear when you click on show more button (down arrow), refer in below screenshot:

[image]

Note: Classic shows single button but in lightning it seems they are separate. Refer highlighted buttons- `View Customer User`, `Disable Custom User` and `Log in to Community as User`. Do not forget to add them on page layout.

Comment: I did check there but not shows up.

Comment: @sfdc, could you update your question with screenshot? Is the button added on the layout? And do you not see these extra buttons- `View Customer User`, `Disable Custom User` and `Log in to Community as User`?

Comment: When I added it to pagelayout Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions then it showed up.Thank you Rahul